# Why AWS Application LBs are counted as Classic LBs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am using only Application Load Balancers (ALB). I can see that on the Load Balancers page on the console ([for example](https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=eu-west-1#LoadBalancers:)).

However, they are actually counted as Classic Load Balancers. Thus, when it reaches the limit, I have to request to increase the limit of the Classic Load Balancers, not ALBs.

Is this a technical issue/bug of AWS?

Answer (score 0):

The limit shown on [Limits for Your Application Load Balancers - Elastic Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html) says:

> Load balancers per region: 20

All types of Load Balancers (Classic, Application, Network) count towards this limit.

Comment: No, it's not correct. First of all, the page you referred to is only for ALB. Besides, I submitted requests to AWS to change both of them, separately. They are not the same, changing one does not affect the other.

Comment: Interesting! The Limits page in the EC2 management does, indeed, show separate limits for each Load Balancer type. However, the "Request Limit Increase" link all point to the same request type. So, it is unclear how it works.